# Ionic app works with ios but does not on android

Tags: android, ionic-framework

My app works fine with "ionic serve", ionic view and "ionic build ios" on ios device. My app also works fine with ionic view on android. 
However, when I run "ionic run android" and install the app on android device, it only shows white blank page and does not work.

People seem having similar issues and some possible solutions are discussed here: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic2-app-show-blank-screen-on-android-device-4-2-2-using-run-command-and-ionicview/39405/17.
However, none of the solutions worked for me. For example, I added crosswalk plugin but did not work.

Does anybody know why it is happening and how to fix it?

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The clue: when white screen, that is down to a syntax error in the script somewhere, a missing dependency in the `app.js`. Chrome on Android is a lot more stricter than Apple's webkit engine so would not see it.

Comment: Yes. The problem was not being able to load external scripts in index.html for Android while ios works fine. I guess this is because as you said Android is a lot more stricter than Apple's webkit. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating ionic, if that doesnt work read the console log maybe via genymotion

Comment: I tried to see the console log via genymotion and found an error that it was not being able to load external scripts such as google APIs. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No Problem, im glad i was able to help! :D

Answer (score 1):

> install the app on android device, it only shows white blank page and does not work.

The big clue in this situation, is down to either a syntax error, missing script, or a dependency injection failure within the `app.js`.

On the Android platform, it is less forgiving in that aspect, as their chromium browser engine, is far more stricter then what would be on iOS's Webkit engine.

The best weapon of defence is to use a lint tool for javascript, this will catch out the extraneous errors, a recommended way, would be to integrate it into the gulp script as a `pre-build` task for example, before doing an actual build.

It can work out to be quite painful when doing a build deploy cycle, without using a lint tool, the extra time spent trying to figure out why a white blank screen greets you, only to realize a few minutes later, it was down to a slight mis-spelling.

Comment: I installed jslint tool on my text editor with your advice and now I see small syntax errors I never realized before. Because android is stricter than IOS's Webkit engine for syntax errors as you mentioned, it is important to fix these small syntax errors in order to make the code work for both ios and android. Thank you for your help!