# Cordova Splashscreen Plugin - Blank white screen instead of splash image on Android

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, splash-screen

Excerpts from my root `config.xml` look like this:

```
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <splash src="www\web\splashscreen\drawable-hdpi\screen.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <splash src="www\web\splashscreen\drawable-ldpi\screen.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <splash src="www\web\splashscreen\drawable-mdpi\screen.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <splash src="www\web\splashscreen\drawable-hdpi\screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="www\web\splashscreen\drawable-ldpi\screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="www\web\splashscreen\drawable-mdpi\screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
</platform>

<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="30000" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true"/>
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="750"/>
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />

<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" spec="~3.2.2" />
```

So I think it's setup okay.  I've tried various other paths to the screen files, but it's not made any difference.  I have verified that the images are in the specified paths prior to `cordova build android`.  No matter what I try, though, I get a blank white screen until my app loads, and no sort of error message or debug output from the splashscreen.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure its blank white screen? Cordova splash screen is grey with a icon in the middle. This sounds more like an issue with the [script somewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337546/ionic-app-works-with-ios-but-does-not-on-android/37392639#37392639) See my answer in that link to explain why,

Comment: @t0mm13b Oh yes, quite sure.  It's all white, just white, for about 10 seconds while my app loads and does its startup.  It's not using my screen.png image, nor Cordova's default.

Answer (score 1):

The [ideal way](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen) to add splash screen images is by placing it in `res/screen/android` inside your cordova project then running the build command.
By doing this all the images gets copied to `platforms/android/res/drawable-*` folder.

As your splash images are not showing, make sure:

- They have copied to `platforms/android/res/drawable-*` folder
  successfully
- Images are in correct size for all screen resolutions